# Использование MTOM в lotus notes

Tags: java, soap, lotus-notes

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, а кто-нибудь использовал MTOM в LN WebServiceProviders?
Если да, то просьба подсказать как настроить  MTOM.